# Half of RAM hardware reserved only on windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, memory

I upgraded my workstation system from 2 to 4 RAM Sticks (16 GB Corsair Vengeance DDR4-3000 DIMM CL16 Dual Kit).
Both RAM kits are from the same vendor and work smoothly together on Ubuntu 20 (LTS version).

[image: System Monitor Ubuntu]

In BIOS, all 4 Sticks get detected. I use the default speed of 2133 MHz and did not do any overclocking, neither on CPU nor RAM.

However, when I boot to Windows (10, Education), only 16 of 32 GB are usable while the remaining 16 GB are *hardware reserved*.

Both Windows and Ubuntu are located on the same SSD hard drive (ca. 250 GB storage for each system).

Did you encounter similar issues when adding RAM to Windows 10?
Since the RAM is working on Ubuntu 20, I assume that the hardware side should be ok.

Best regards
Chips

Comment: Google the issue, there are too many causes for this in Windows>>>>>>>>https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=TPCmXrSKLdLSsAWR2JKQAw&q=windows+10+hardware+reserved+memory&oq=windows+10+hardware+reserved+memory&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzICCAAyAggAMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHlDiCVjiCWDNDWgAcAB4AIABRIgBRJIBATGYAQCgAQKgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi04LvB7IjpAhVSKawKHRGsBDIQ4dUDCAk&uact=5

Comment: Not a problem with Windows 10 itself (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-limits-for-windows-releases#physical-memory-limits-windows-10). Either something is not right with your hardware (not physically in the slot properly) or you have enabled a memory limit somehow, either in the BIOS or in Windows itself. https://superuser.com/questions/741266/limit-total-ram-usage-to-certain-value-in-windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is all my extra RAM marked as "hardware reserved" in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/56157/why-is-all-my-extra-ram-marked-as-hardware-reserved-in-windows-7)